# What is its equivalent in Kotlin for &+ as in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, bitwise-operators

This is a line in Swift code that I want to use in Kotlin :

```
 // var hash: UInt32 = 0
 hash = hash &+ UInt32(bytes[i])
```

It is adding numbers bit-wise and then ignore the overflow.

See "Value overflow" in the Swift language documentation: ( https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html )

> However, when you specifically want an overflow condition to truncate the number of available bits, you can opt in to this behavior rather than triggering an error. Swift provides three arithmetic overflow operators that opt in to the overflow behavior for integer calculations. These operators all begin with an ampersand (`&`):
>
> - Overflow addition (`&+`)
> - Overflow subtraction (`&-`)
> - Overflow multiplication (`&*`)

What is its equivalent in Kotlin ? I didn't see it in official documentation.

Comment: What is the train of thought that leads you to believe all languages _should_ be identical in features?

Comment: i am checking if there is something similar, if that isn't understandable.

Comment: It is, but it's probably more helpful to redact the question in a way that doesn't appear to be a demand for a non-existent feature. There are similar approaches as you have been shown, yet are reluctant to show any kind of appreciation for others as it seems to be a standard practice on your questions.

Comment: I suggest you first try reproducing Swift's overflow behavior of `+` in Kotlin. Then you'll realize your question should have been "what is the equivalent of Swift's `+` in Kotlin" because the answer to your current question is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin does not raise errors in the event of integer overflow. Kotlin is based on the JVM so it doesn't have unsigned types either. So you can simply add the values:

```
val hash : Int = ...
val bytes : ByteArray = ...
hash += bytes[i]
```

Of course, `Byte` is signed in Kotlin too, so you might need to do value conversion when widening it:

```
val byte : Byte = bytes[i]
val byteAsInt : Int = byte.toInt()
if (byteAsInt < 0) byteAsInt = 255 + byteAsInt + 1

hash += byteAsInt
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator like this but Kotlin can do the same:

```
val a: Byte = 100
val b: Byte = 121
val x: Byte = (((a + b) shl 8) shr 8).toByte()
println(x)
```

so the operator can be created:

```
infix fun Byte.`&+`(b: Byte): Byte = (((this + b) shl 8) shr 8).toByte()
```

and used like this:

```
val a: Byte = 100
val b: Byte = 121
val x: Byte = a `&+` b
println(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I plan to use this java code from my kotlin file:

```
public static byte addBytesWithOverflow(byte a, byte b) {
    int val = (a + b) & 0xFF;
    return (byte) val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after trying so long
I was trying to implement below line in function same as iOS
hash = (hash << 5) &+ hash &+ Int(char.asciiValue!)

```
fun String.djb2() : Long {
    var hash : Long = 5381    
    for (char in this) {
     val code = char.toInt()
      hash = ((hash shl 5) + hash+code).toLong()      
    }
    return hash
```

}